# Can You Buy a Catan Border That Fits?

Tags: catan, catan-cities-and-knights, board-game-adaptations, custom-game-pieces

"The border of the 4th edition Settlers of Catan is too small for the board hexes.  To be exact, each hexagonal tile is about 79 mm wide.  Five of them, end to end, form the longest stretch of land requiring 395 mm of width within the shore tiles. And now, the distance between the shore tiles? About 393 mm. Yup, 2 mm short."  http://www.tinysci.com/2010/07/04/the-settlers-of-catan-something-completely-different/

Lots of custom boards out there because of this problem.

Is there an inexpensive commercially-available border that actually fits?

Comment: This is an old question that has recently reappeared on the main page. I'm voting to close it because, as written, it is looking for a specific product, which sounds pretty similar to game recommendation questions. While at one time, those questions were allowed, [they are currently banned](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/663/3389). Closing seems to be the best way to not attract new answers to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Get a crafty friend to cut a set of interlocking tiles for you.

http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:6681

Or print a set of border pieces.

http://www.thingiverse.com/thing:6436